Covariance matrix residuals equation
I'm to show that the covariance matrix of the residuals are
$$Cov(\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{\hat{Y}}) = \sigma^2(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{H})$$
I know that $Cov(\mathbf{Y}) = \sigma^2\mathbf{I}$ and that $Cov(\mathbf{\hat{Y}}) = \sigma^2\mathbf{H}$
Entry $(i,j)$ in the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{\hat{Y}}$ will be $Cov(Y_i-\hat{Y_i},Y_j-\hat{Y_j})$, and by the distributive property of covariance this is $Cov(Y_i, Y_j)+Cov(Y_i,-\hat{Y_j})+Cov(-\hat{Y_i},Y_j)+Cov(\hat{-Y_i},\hat{-Y_j})$
Entry $(i,j)$ in the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{Y}$ is $Cov(Y_i, Y_j)$
Entry $(i,j)$ in the covariance matrix of $\mathbf{\hat{Y}}$ is $Cov(\hat{Y_i}, \hat{Y_j})$
So, I wouldn't dare to write $Cov(\mathbf{Y}-\mathbf{\hat{Y}}) = Cov(\mathbf{Y}) - Cov(\mathbf{\hat{Y}})$...
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Express the residual in terms of $\mathbf Y. $ The residual is $(\mathbf I -\mathbf H) \mathbf Y. $
So, the covariance matrix would be $(\mathbf I -\mathbf H) \operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf Y) (\mathbf I -\mathbf H) ^\top.$ Use the property that $(\mathbf I -\mathbf H) $ is idempotent and $\operatorname{Cov}(\mathbf Y) =\sigma^2\mathbf I. $

I completely overlooked $Cov(\mathbf{AU})=\mathbf{A}Cov(\mathbf{U})\mathbf{A}^T$, thanks!
